# I need to implement a simple shuffle and sort alogrithm as a class

Tags: c++, sorting

I have created the class

```
   void NmbSetA::sort(){
    bool swaped = false;
    int minPos, tmp;
    for(int i = 0; i < (size_ - 1); i++){
        minPos = i;
        for(int j = (i + 1); j < size_; j++){
            if(dataField_[j] < dataField_[minPos]){
            minPos = j;
            swaped = true;
            }
        }
        if(swaped){
            tmp = dataField_[i];
            dataField_[i] = dataField_[minPos];
            dataField_[minPos] = tmp;
        }
        }
    }
```

and the class

```
void NmbSetA::shuffle(){
        for(int i=size_-1;i>=1;i--){
            int j = rand()%size_;
            int tmp;
            tmp=dataField_[i];
            dataField_[i]=j;
            dataField_[j]=tmp;
        }
```

My output looks like this, what can I improve?

```
turn 1:
shuffled: []
sorted  : []

turn 2:
shuffled: [9180128]
sorted  : [0]

turn 3:
shuffled: [0, 10]
sorted  : [0, 2]

turn 4:
shuffled: [11, 6, 7]
sorted  : [0, 1, 2]

turn 5:
shuffled: [0, 2, 1, 9]
sorted  : [0, 1, 2, 2]

turn 6:
shuffled: [5, 8, 7, 0, 7]
sorted  : [0, 1, 2, 3, 5]
```

It should put out a shuffled array from 1 to turn n-1 and sort it. The Way the array is created is given and cannot be changed. I only should add the method to sort and shuffle the created array. Sorting it from the lowest to the highest number.

Comment: This question's shown code does not meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mre]. This means it's unlikely that anyone here can conclusively answer the question; but only guess at the most. You should [edit] your question to show a minimal example, no more than one or two pages of code (the "minimal" part), that everyone else can cut/paste, compile, run, and reproduce the described issue (the "reproducible" part) ***exactly as shown*** (this includes any ancillary information, like the input to the program). See [ask] for more information.

Comment: You might also be interested in https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ - your question appears to be more suitable there!

Comment: If your shuffled array has different content than the sorted one your code probably is broken. We need a [mre], but `dataField_[i]=j;` in `shuffle` is probably a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the STL to solve your problem. The STL has a sort and a shuffle algorithm:

```
constexpr std::size_t size;

class NmbSetA {
public:
    NmbSetA();
    void sort();
    void shuffle() {
        std::shuffle(dataField_, dataField_ + size_, g);
    }
 
private:
    std::random_device rd;
    std::mt19937 g;
    int dataField_[size];
    std::size_t size_ = size;
};

NmbSetA::NmbSetA() : g(rd()) {}
void NmbSetA::sort() {
    std::sort(dataField_, dataField_ + size_);
}
void NmbSetA::shuffle() {
    std::shuffle(dataField_, dataField_ + size_, g);
}
```